# Printing out a TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> Key and Mapped Values

Tags: java, printing

```
I have a TreeMap <String, TreeSet <String>>

{Heat = [Bosh, Lebron, Wade], Nets =[DWill, KG], Sonics = null, Warriors = [Curry,Iggy,Thompson]}
```

and I want to print out.

```
   Heat Bosh Lebron Wade
   Nets DWill KG
   Sonics 
   Warriors Curry Iggy Thompson
```

I've tried

```
    for ( String w : listNBA){
        System.out.print( w + " ");           
        if (treemap.containsKey(w))
            System.out.println(treemap.get(w));
        else
            System.out.println( "" ); // print nothing if team doesn't exist
```

But this isn't quite right either, and it's output is...

```
 Heat [Bosh, Lebron, Wade]
 Nets [DWill, KG]
 Sonics null
 Warriors [Curry,Iggy,Thompson]
```

So, my question is: Is there any easy way to convert a TreeSet to a String in my print method?

Comment: For each key, for each element in the corresponding value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (Entry<String, TreeSet<String>> mapEntry : treemap.entrySet()) {
    stringBuilder.append(mapEntry.getKey());
    if (mapEntry.getValue() != null) {
        for (String setEntry : mapEntry.getValue()) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ").append(setEntry);
        }
    }
    stringBuilder.append("\n");
}

System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has a `String.join` method that works great for this:

```
for ( String w : listNBA){
    System.out.print( w + " ");           
    if (treemap.containsKey(w) && treemap.get(w) != null)
        System.out.println(String.join(" ",treemap.get(w)));
    else
        System.out.println( "" ); // print nothing if team doesn't exist
}
```

Note that while your original `System.out.println(treemap.get(w))` printed out `null` if the `get` method returned `null`, `String.join` will throw a `NullPointerException` if it gets a null parameter.  Thus, I've added a null check to the previous `if`.

`join`'s first parameter is a string that will be inserted between each input string.  It can either take a variable number of `String` (or any other `CharSequence`) arguments, or an array of `String` (or other `CharSequence`).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the entry set and print out the key and the corresponsing value.

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, TreeSet <String>> entry : treemap.entrySet())
 {
     System.out.print( entry.getKey() + " "); 
     System.out.print( entry.getValue());
 }
```